# Getting different behavior when passing Model to BeginForm method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I've come across a weird situation. I have the following viewmodel:

```
public class Document{
   public string DocNumber{get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   //omitted for brevity
}
```

There's a view called EditDocument strongly typed to this model. On another view I have the following action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDocument", "InwardDocument", new { docNumber=Model.DocNumber},null)
```

Here's the `EditDocument` action method in my `InwardDocument` controller:

```
public ActionResult EditDocument(string docNumber){
 DocumentRepository repository = new DocumentCitizenRepository();
 Document doc = repository.Documents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DocNumber == docNumber);
 return View(viewName:"EditDocument",model: doc);
}
```

And finally, here's the EditDocument.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDocument","InwardDocument")){
   //omitted for brevity
   <input type="submit" value="Save">
}
```

The SaveDocument action method receives the Document object as model. When I debug this method I find out that DocNumber property of the model is null. But when debugging the EditDocument method the value for DocNumber property of the Document retrieved from the repository is not null ("1" in in case). 
 As a workaround I tried to pass the Model to BeginForm method like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDocument","InwardDocument",new RouteValueDictionary(Model)))
```

It indeed helped to solve the problem but I have two concerns:

1. Why did passing Model work? Isn't Model the same as whatever is passed from the action method?
2. Passing Model solves above problem but it brings another bane with it. If I go this way I get false checkbox value which is described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466610/radiobutton-checkbox-and-select-elements-dont-get-populated-accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass `DocNumber` in a hidden field in the form otherwise it will be posted null:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDocument","InwardDocument"))
{

@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.DocNumber)

<input type="submit" value="Save">

}
```

Comment: Why do I have to create a hidden field for that? My Model already contains a property? And besides that, again, why does passing Model solve the issue?

Comment: because the model properties ware posted via input controls inside form so we need to create input control for each item, the ones we don't want user to edit or show, we use hidden fields, otherwise those properties will be posted null

Comment: OK, @Ehsan, I understood why I need to have a hidden field for that. Basically because there's no where to bind the model property to. There needs to be an html element to keep the model property values. But I would be glad to know why passing Model to the BeginForm method works?

Comment: what you mean by ``why passing Model to the BeginForm method works?``??

Comment: If I do `@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDocument","InwardDocument",new RouteValueDictionary(Model)))` the problem vanishes even if I don't add the hidden value for DocNumber. Why? I know that the model is passed implicitly, but that way I have the issue I've mentioned, but if I pass the Model explicitly, problem disappears.

Comment: yes that if you are getting all properties with correct then you can do that way as well, basically when we create from to create textbox and take user input and in post that reflects in model properties